# Google Analytics > Engagement > Duration - Make Custom Times

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, metrics

I need to find the following metrics. How many users stayed for 2 seconds, how many stayed for 5 seconds, how many stayed for 10 seconds.

On Google Analytics they have something very similar but it generalizes everything from 0-10 seconds.

Is it possible to make my own durations like 0-2, 2-5, and 5-10?

[image]

Comment: Note the caveats of Session Duration. Session Duration is taken from the difference in time's between the first and last hit.  For a session duration to be 2/5/10 seconds, a user must land on your page and load a new page (or trigger an event) within 2/5/10 seconds. The report you are outlining will not display if a user arrived at the website and stayed on the page for 2/5/10 seconds then left the website (a bounced session).

Answer (score 1):

Not in that exact report. But you can do that creating a custom segment.

For example the following custom segment will give you visits with duration between 2 and 5.

[image: visitDuration Segment]